# Reference on Grothendieck trace formula

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, arithmetic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory

I need to refer to the so-called Grothendieck trace formula, but after checking tens of Google pages, I still cannot find a proper reference on this topic. Could anyone tell me some good book/papers on that? Many thanks.

Comment: Did you look at Freitag-Reinhardt: *Étale cohomology and the Weil conjecture*, Ergebnisse der Mathematik und ihrer Grenzgebiete **13** (1988), in particular Chapter II, $\S 4$?

Comment: Thanks so much, I will certainly check that!

Answer (score 15):

Sorry for giving an answer instead of a comment, but I am new to MathOverflow and hence I cannot comment yet.

The original references are:

- SGA 4.1/2, Chapter 2 (MR 0463174, that can be downloaded [here](https://publications.ias.edu/sites/default/files/Number32.pdf));
- SGA 5, Exposé III (ZBL 0355.14004, that can be downloaded [here](https://wstein.org/sga/circle/SGA5.pdf)).

and you can find modern expositions in

- Milne, "Etale cohomology", Theorem 12.3 (MR 0559531). See also some [lecture notes](https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/LEC.pdf) by the same author;
- Freitag-Kiehl, as pointed out by Francesco Polizzi (MR 0926276)
- Notes of the Stanford Number Theory learning seminar ([here](http://virtualmath1.stanford.edu/~conrad/Weil2seminar/));
- The Stacks Project, [Chapter 58](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0F5P);

Comment: This is better as an answer than as a comment; thanks. (And now that you have more than 50 points of rep, you can comment!)

Comment: Many thanks, this list is certainly very useful to me